# How to convert Flutter's Future<dynamic> to Future<other_type>?

Tags: flutter, future

In the past, I use the http Client which returns `Future<Response>`. I notice that I can return other type inside the `.then()` method and the end type result will change according to the type of what I returned inside the then.

But when I change to use a package which returns `Future<dynamic>`, returning different type inside the `.then()` doesn't change the end result type anymore. It keeps resulting in `Future<dynamic>`. But I can assure that the dynamic type is a `Response` type. Here's what I have tried:

1st:

```
Future<Response> get(String url) =>
    fetcher.get(url).then((response) => response as Response); // error: Unhandled Exception: type 'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Future<Response>'
```

2nd:

```
Future<Response> get(String url) =>
    fetcher.get(url) as Future<Response>; // error: Unhandled Exception: type 'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Future<Response>'
```

3rd:

```
Future<Response> get(String url) =>
    fetcher.get(url).then((response) { 
        final result = response as Response;
        return result;
    }); // error: Unhandled Exception: type 'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Future<Response>'
```

In the past:

```
Future<List<Model>> get(String url) =>
    client.get(url).then((response) => Model.fromJson(response.body)); // working.
```

Package that I used for this: https://pub.dev/packages/twitter_api#-example-tab-

EDIT: to clarify about the fetcher:

```
import 'package:twitter_api/twitter_api.dart';
import "package:http/http.dart";


twitterApi fetcher = twitterApi(
    consumerKey: consumerApiKey,
    consumerSecret: consumerApiSecretKey,
    token: locker.session?.token,
    tokenSecret: locker.session?.secret
);

Future<Response> get(String path) {
    final split = url.split("?");
    final onlyPath = split[0];
    final onlyParam = split.length > 1 ? split[1] : "";
    final options = Map.fromIterable(onlyParam.split("&").where((it) => it.contains("=")), key: (e) => e.split("=")[0] as String, value: (e) => e.split("=")[1] as String);
    return fetcher.getTwitterRequest("GET", onlyPath.replaceFirst("/", "", options: options).then((response) {
        debugPrint ("GET ${response.request.url} Response: ${response.body}");
        return response as Response;
    }); 
}
```

Output:

```
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: type 'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Future<Response>'
#0      TwitterApiProvider.fetchUser (package:feazy/src/resources/twitter_api_provider.dart:11:70)
#1      Repository.fetchUser (package:feazy/src/resources/repository.dart:19:27)
#2      _HomeState.twitterLogin (package:feazy/src/ui/home.dart:50:21)
...
GET https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/show.json?screen_name=somescreenname Response: {"id":<int>,"id_str":<string>,"name":"Some name","screen_name":"somescreenname",...
```

EDIT 2: on further check, I notice that on the IDE, the IDE tells me that the return type of the `fetcher.getTwitterRequest()` is not `Future<dynamic>`, but `dynamic`. So I change my code like this, but it still won't work.

```
Future<Response> get (String path) {
    ...
    final future = authClient.getTwitterRequest(...).then((response) {
        debugPrint ("POST ${response.request.url} Response: ${response.body}");
        return response as Response;
    });
    final futureResponse = future as Future<Response>;
    return futureResponse;
}
```

In this case, the error is on the `final futureResponse = future as Future<Response>;`, saying the same thing: `Unhandled Exception: type 'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Future<Response>' in type cast`.

Comment: What is this `fetcher`? An import identifier of [http](https://pub.dev/packages/http) package?

Comment: How do you use them the 1st, 2nd, and 3rd function?

Comment: @CrazyLazyCat I have updated the question with more actual code.

Comment: @Hian I have updated the question with more actual code.

Comment: @pskink I have updated the question with more actual code. Maybe you can see the problem in my code better?

Comment: btw your `get` method returns `Future<void>` as it does not return any value at the end of its body

Comment: @pskink it has. I just made another edit a minute ago adding that missing return. My actual code already has return too.

Comment: what is in `twitter_api_provider.dart` line #11?

Comment: @pskink it's the api provider, basically just a wrapper for request functions. `Future<Response> fetchUser ({ String screenName, int userId } ) => _request.get("/users/show.json?${identity(screenName, userId)}");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO, all of your examples are okay, but the error actually tell us that you are tried to cast `Future<Response>` into `Future<dynamic>`

**UPDATE**

You could use `async await`, something like this:

```
Future<Response> get(String path) async {
    final split = url.split("?");
    final onlyPath = split[0];
    final onlyParam = split.length > 1 ? split[1] : "";
    final options = Map.fromIterable(onlyParam.split("&").where((it) => it.contains("=")), key: (e) => e.split("=")[0] as String, value: (e) => e.split("=")[1] as String);
    final response = await fetcher.getTwitterRequest("GET", onlyPath.replaceFirst("/", "", options: options); 
    return response as Response;
}
```

Comment: Yes. More accurately, I'm trying to cast the type within the `Future` into another type, but still enclosed within a `Future`. Usually I have no problem converting `Future<Response>` into, say, `Future<List<Model>>`. But here I have problem converting `Future<dynamic>` into `Future<Response>`. It's like Dart ignoring my typecast `response as Response`.

Comment: `await` ? I'll try it right now, but doesn't that will make the app cannot run multiple requests in parallel?

Comment: it still able to run multiple requests because we add `async` to the function >> `Future<Response> get(String path) async {`. Im assuming that `getTwitterRequest` can do multiple requests

Comment: Yes, after using await, this is now working. Thanks.